# How could I change my app name in soundcloud login/signup page?

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I have an iOS app which integrates SoundCloud. Recently we have changed our iOS app name and when someone wants to login/signup to SoundCloud through my app it is showing the previous app name. I have checked the settings of SoundCloud in their settings page but there is no option to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to change your SoundCloud app name, website, or redirect URI at this time.  The previous solution was to create a new app, but at this time (as of September 9th, 2018), SoundCloud has closed new API application requests.